# Regular HDD as NAS in OpenMediaVault?

Tags: hard-disk, nas

I plan to build a small office server with OpenMediaVault installed. This server will have to carry several HDD that are accessible throughout local network. The server will be active 24/7 weekdays, and rested through weekend. Is regular HDD viable for this build?

The workload of that HDD will not be challenging, its main purpose is to have a centralized backup for my office. Why should I spend extra bucks for HDD specifically made for NAS?

Comment: this isn't really about unix or linux, it probably belongs on https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ - but note that consumer "NAS" labelled drives (like seagate ironwolf or WD Red) aren't significantly more expensive these days than other drives.  They have slightly different firmware, more suited to 24/7 operation.   That said, I've run 24/7 home servers for years with cheap drives - in my experience, the main issue is cooling - if the drives or enclosure aren't adequately cooled, the drives will have a much shorter life.

Comment: BTW, use RAID-1 or ZFS mirroring or similar.   IMO & IME, parity raid like RAID-5/6 may give more storage but it just isn't worth the risk.  The resync load (when replacing a drive after a failure) is likely to cause one of the other drives to die, losing everything.

Comment: In your 24/7 home servers, are the drives connected at all times or occasionally? I imagine my server would have less read/write activities, but will always be connected to 2-3 clients through SMB/AFP. Will it affect the lifespan of a regular HDD?

Comment: connected and running all the time, 24/7.  The servers might be rebooted once or twice a year (for kernel upgrades or whatever), but are otherwise always on.   BTW, I've also used cheap consumer drives in file servers for small businesses, university departments, ISP web servers, and more.   an oft-forgotten fact about RAID is that the "I" stands for "Inexpensive"...the point is to achieve resilience through redundancy, and the cheaper drives are, the more redundancy you can afford.

Comment: I also use at least mirrored drives in **everything** (i don't have any machines at home that don't have at least 1 mirrored pair of drives).  That effectively doubles the price of all my disk storage, but my data and my time arre worth a lot more to me than that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a hardware question, not about unix or linux.